# javascript unterminated character class

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var badCode = "\(INST1,\\[0,";
var regex = new RegExp(badCode, "igm");
```

gets "unterminated character class" error.

How to fix?

TIA

trying suggestions from responders to this post, please see the following screen prints (you might have to right-click on images and open in new tab to make legible):
note values of new_bad_thing (equiv of badCode above)
[image]

and here is the screen print when I hit the run button (please note the error message):

[image]

Comment: I get `SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(INST1,\[0,/: Unterminated group`, i.e. the parenthesis (char 1 in string) doesn't have a matching `)`. It is being treated as a group as `"\(" === "("`, you need to write `"\\("` to get `\(`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put another backslash at `badCode`:

```
var badCode = "\\(INST1,\\[0,";
var regex = new RegExp(badCode, "igm");
```

since you need one to escape `(` inside the regex itself (signal it that it's a literal parentheis) and one escape for javascript.

Comment: Tried that, badCode = "\\\(INST1,\\\[0,", still getting "unterminated character class".  Verified that badCode is what you showed in chrome debugger.

Comment: That's odd. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wdzV6/) which demonstrates it works.

Comment: you're right. And yet, as you see from my screen shots, that's what I'm getting.  Could it be a bug in chrome?

Comment: Found the problem: even tho the debugger shows the "new_bad_thing" string as being the same as your "badcode", the chaining of the ".replace(/\\/g,"\\\\")" is causing the problem.  When I take it out, the code works.

Answer (score 3):

No, it gets "unterminated parenthetical", because you've forgotten to escape the backslash. Why not use a regular expression literal?

```
var regex = /\(INST1,\[0,/igm;
```

Comment: because badCode can be any number of things, I'm just using a literal as an example

Comment: @davej: Then escape the first backslash with another backslash. But the error can't be "unterminated character class" with that string. Something is awry.

Comment: thanks for your input, I edited the original post to show what I'm getting.

Comment: @davej: It seems like the replacements should be `\\)` and `\\(`, not `\\\\)` and `\\\\(`.

Comment: that's what I had originally, but I changed it match ofer zelig's solution

Comment: @davej: My mistake. `\\\\]` and `\\\\[` instead of `\\]` and `\\[`. It looks like the debugger or the watcher isn't re-escaping things. (It happens.) They do actually need to be quadruple-escaped.